# Eloquent how to search in relation's values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables with the following fields:

**person**: id, lastname, firstname

**phoneboookentry**: id, name

I have the following two models:

```
class Person extends Eloquent
{

    public static $table = 'personphonebookentries';

    public function phonebookentry()
    {
        return $this->has_one('Phonebookentry', 'id');
    }

}
```

```
class Phonebookentry extends Eloquent
{
     public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('Person', 'id');
    }

}
```

I can't figure out how to get all Persons that have a specific firstname OR a specific number.

I've tried :

```
Person::or_where('firstname', 'LIKE', '_name_')->phonebookentry()->or_where('number', '=', '_number_')->get();
```

I need help on finding out how to get that done :)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case a simple relation not gonna help as you want to constrain the People results based on the relation which is a second query.

With this schema you would need to do a join, something like this in case you add a person_id to the phoneboookentry table:

```php
Person::join('phoneboookentry', 'person.id', '=', 'phoneboookentry.person_id')
    ->where('person.firstname', 'LIKE', "%$name%")
    ->or_where('phoneboookentry.number', '=', $number)
    ->get('person.*');
```

But for every one-to-one relationship it is strongly adevised to think about the schema, there is a high probability that you'll be better off merging the tables. Overnormalization is not helping usually.

Also a few miscellaneous points:

1. You have "personphonebookentries" as a table, but you said you have person table.
2. Specifying id as a foreign key is not a good thing, keeping the two table in sync just creates problems.
3. It is unnecesary and wrong to use `or_where()` everywhere, just use it where it when it's neccesary.
4. From the point when you run any query or relational method on a model you are working on a query object, you can't execute relational methods on query objects. (`phonebookentry()`) You have to have a result model.

Comment: Thank us so much TLGreg: it works great.
Just to answer a few of your points.
0 : I've go a phonebookentries table which can point to person (as here) or to companies or to facilities with specific data related to each of those types. Is it overnormalization still ?
1 : Yes indeed, what's wrong with that from your point of view ?
2 : I inherited from this schema, I'll correct it as soon as Laravel and Eloquent are ok
3 : I use this query to search for user matching one of those criteria
4 : Ok that's the point I was missing :)